# Grafana Datediff with Synapse Datasource

Tags: sql, grafana, azure-synapse, datediff

I have a simple query that works within Azure Synapse using its built-in MySql Server:

```
SELECT TOP (15)
  cast ("Betriebstag" as DATETIME),
  CONVERT (VARCHAR, "Betriebstag", 34) as "betriebstag",
  "MWNR",
  "kwhUsed" as "Ist-Verbrauch",
  "kWh_prediction" as "ML Prognose",
  "kwh_prediction_linear_temperature" as "Lineare Prognose",
  cast ("prediction_written" as DATETIME)
FROM [dbo].[XYZ]
WHERE ("Betriebstag" BETWEEN '2023-08-01' AND '2023-08-15') 
AND "MWNR" = 4021
AND DATEDIFF(day, "Betriebstag", "prediction_written") = -1 
AND kwhUsed is not null
ORDER BY "Betriebstag" asc
```

In Grafana I use the same database. However, using the same query I get an error:

```
convert frame from rows error: mssql: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Is there any difference in using DATEDIFF in Grafana? Or is there something wrong in casting my timestamp variables to DATETIME?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably your client and Grafana are using different client libraries for connection with different formatting settings. So one can successfully convert date from string of your format to actual datetime. I'm not sure which of the conversions here is causing error, but you can easily find out by removing them one by one.

Comment: And that's not a mysql query. Perhaps you meant ms sql.